# Having to store too many image files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, ipad

So I have a huge app.  It is full of features, most of which require a couple images, and all of which have to be saved as part of the binary file.  I worked really hard before the release to get under the 20MB threshold, to make the app more accessible to users.  My release binaryt was 18.1MB.

So now, with the new iPad and its retina display, what should I do about updating all of my images for this new display.  If I did include an updated copy, I would be way over the 20MB limit.  Currently, I store some image files on my sever, and download/cache them as the user needs them, but im hesitant to do this with major features because I'm concerned some users may not always have internet access.  And without some of those images, the app is useless.

Is there any way I can have an iPhone only install the iPhone graphics, and visa versa?

Comment: where ever you have table views in your app, try to load those table views with Lazy loading, this may decrease the count of images to be used and as Jack told apple has increased the memory to 50MB, so this may be helpful to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has since raised the limit for all devices to 50 MB due to the release of the new iPad. This should hopefully allow you to fit all of the pictures in your app bundle.

Answer (score 2):

One approach to minimize the size of your files is by compressing your PNG files. This will only minimize the size, and the images will continue to work correctly.

The links provided below will help you find a crusher you desire.

[PNG Crush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)

[PNG Compressor](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/38512/png-compressor)

[ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/)

Comment: So just to clarify, if I compress a file, I won't have to uncompress it on the device.  It will just work?

Comment: Yes, the device automatically decompresses it.